# Parallax Scrolling issue

Tags: c#, xna

Let me just show you my current code first:

```
backgroundPos = 
    new Vector2(camera.centre.X - (textureBackground.Width - 1920) * 
                (camera.centre.X / levelWidth),
                camera.centre.Y - (textureBackground.Height - 1080) *
                (camera.centre.Y / levelHeight))
```

What I'm trying to do:
[image]

I'm trying to make a type of parallax scrolling with only one background, where the position of the picture (top left) is following the camera's position (also top left), but it's position reduces the more right and/or down you go, according to the picture above.

What happens right now is; it works for the top and left side (the picture's position is the same as the cameras), but when the camera is on the bottom or right, the whole picture isn't shown.

How do I fix this?

Also: `camera.centre[x, y] = [top, left]`, not actually the center of it.

Comment: You are making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Just make the backgrounds XY be equal to a percentage of the cameras XY. That way, the more you move in a direction, the more it will follow, but not at the same speed that the camera moves. I.e. parallaxing.

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.